# Hover with id not working

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
<style type="text/css">
    #parent:hover #abc{
        display: block ;
    }
</style>
```

The :hover in this is not working
The following was the code used. Whenever the mouse hovers over #parent #abc should be displayed. But this it is not happening so.

```
<a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" id="parent">LIK2</a>
<ul style="list-style-type: none;margin: 0px; margin-left:100px;position: absolute; top: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color:green; display: none" id="abc" class="w3-bar-block">
    <li class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link1 </li>
    <li class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link1</li>
    <li class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link1</li>
</ul>
```

please can someone figure out the problem.

EDIT:
Entire code

```
 <div class="w3-dropdown-hover" style="width: 50%;">
    <button class="w3-button">SomeButton</button>
    <div class="w3-bar-block w3-black w3-dropdown-content   " id="xyz" style="width: 100px; ">
        <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button">LIK1</a>
        <div style="margin:0px; padding: 0px; position: relative;" id="parent">
            <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button">LIK2</a>
            <ul style="list-style-type: none;margin: 0px; margin-left:100px;position: absolute; top: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color:green; display: none" id="abc" class="w3-bar-block">
                <li class="w3-bar-item w3-button">
                    Link1
                </li>
                <li class="w3-bar-item w3-button">
                    Link1
                </li>
                <li class="w3-bar-item w3-button">
                    Link1
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>      
        <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button">LIN3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you set inline style for #abc and never let you set other style in head , you should set #abc style in a head , like this :

CSS:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    #abc {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0px;
        margin-left: 100px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background-color: green;
        display: none;
    }

    div#parent:hover > ul#abc {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

HTML :

```
<div id="parent">
    <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button">LIK2</a>
    <ul id="abc" class="w3-bar-block">
        <li class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link1 </li>
        <li class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link1</li>
        <li class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `adjacent` sibling selector(+) or `general` sibling selector(~) to select the siblings. Check below snippet for reference. Check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp) for more details about Combinators selectors.

```css
#parent:hover ~#abc{
  display: block !important;  
}
```

```html
<a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" id="parent">LIK2</a>
<ul style="list-style-type: none;margin: 0px; margin-left:100px;position: absolute; top: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color:green; display: none" id="abc" class="w3-bar-block">
  <li class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link1 </li>
  <li class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link1</li>
  <li class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works, BUT is quite not stable. Whenever mouse is over the <li> elements the <ul> is not displayed

Answer (score 1):

try like this, you can give appropriate ids as you needed to do so.

```css
li:hover ul{
  display: block !important;  
}
```

```html
<ul style="" id="abc" class="w3-bar-block">
<li>
LIK2<br>
        <ul id="inner" style="list-style-type: none;margin: 0px; margin-left:100px;position: absolute; top: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color:green; display: none">

          <li class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link1 </li>
          <li class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link1</li>

          <li class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link1</li>
        </ul>  
  </li>
</ul>
```

hope this helps

Comment: @Prajval M this is stable :)